# MMdrawercontroller: click on the centerVC when the left menu is opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, mmdrawercontroller

I use `MMdrawercontroller` in my objective-c application to display a left menu. I want when the menu is opened, to enable the click on the little part displayed of the centerVC.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you please provide me the objective c version? If I understood, I have to enable the gesture for the centerVC controller when the menu is opened. Isn't it?

Comment: I have those lines self.drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModeBezelPanningCenterView; 
    self.drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;

Comment: hey LIg use this one :

mmDrawerController?.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.tapCenterView

just use -> .tapCenterView Properties

Comment: @GOPALVASANI closeDrawerGestureModeMask or openDrawerGestureModeMask? The problem is when the menu is opened

Comment: hey LIg tell me , worked or not ?

Comment: Yeeeeees it woooorks thanks a lot!

Comment: @GOPALVASANI But the manuel gesture close is not working now :/

Comment: @GOPALVASANI I have now a problem with the gesture mode. It's not working now? only the center tap can close the menu not also the gesture

Comment: okay , so you just described that you want  to close the menu with tap on the centre View in your question , but now you want to close it with swipping the view too . so that you can use  .all property rather than .left

Comment: @GOPALVASANI Where can I please set this property?

Comment: Hey Llg grow up buddy 

1: mmDrawerController?.openDrawerGestureModeMask = .all
2:mmDrawerController?.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = .all

Comment: @GOPALVASANI Thanks a lot!!! Can you please make it as an answer?

Comment: it will be in swift , is that okay ?

Comment: okay @GOPALVASANI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        // Suppose you have three ViewContollers 
        // Left , Front and Right

        let frontView = frontview(nibName: "frontview" , bundle: nil)
        let leftView = leftview(nibName: "leftview" , bundle: nil)
        let rightView = rightview(nibName: "rightview" , bundle: nil)


        let mmDrawerController = MMDrawerController(center: frontView, leftDrawerViewController: leftView, rightDrawerViewController: rightView)

        // Here you can use .all , .panningCenterView , .tapCenterView
        // as per your requirements..

        mmDrawerController?.openDrawerGestureModeMask = .all
        mmDrawerController?.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = .all

        self.window?.rootViewController = mmDrawerController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the gesture when define de DrawerController. This code is Swift, but it will be very similar in ObjC

```
    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: self.centNav, rightDrawerViewController: rightViewController)

    centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.None
    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView
```

I put MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.None because i open the menu with a button. If you want to open with gesture you can define in that line

Comment: How can I enable the gesture close also?

Comment: select one of the options, PanCenterView is your option